# Rails 4 - two tables on same page, query for second table ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page called `lastthree.html.erb` that is displaying data for the Ownerships model. I have a partial called `_nextpick.html.erb`, also for Ownerships model.

In my `ownerships_controller.rb`, I have two definitions:

```
def nextpick
  @ownerships = Ownership.take(Rails.application.config.counter).last(1)
end

def lastthree
  @ownerships = Ownership.take(Rails.application.config.counter - 1).last(3)  
end
```

If I make `nextpick` its own page (`nextpick.html.erb`) and access it from the menu, it works fine and I get the correct result. But if I render it as a partial from `lastthree.html.erb`, I get the results of the `lastthree` query. Its doesn't matter where I render it on the page.

Why is the `nextpick` query being ignored? Is there anyway to overcome this?

Both pages use the same code to display the data:

```
<% @ownerships.each do |ownership| %>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= ownership.round %></td>
    <td><%= ownership.pick %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag ownership.team.logo.url(:medium) %></td>
    <td><%= ownership.team.name %></td>

    <% if ownership.player_id == nil %>
    <% else %>
      <td><%= ownership.player.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where is `nextpick` being called? Are you expecting `nextpick` to be called because that's the name of a partial that's being rendered? Rendering a partial doesn't cause any controller methods to be invoked. The router decides which controller method is invoked, and it will invoke only a single controller method: The one that matches the route.

Comment: Very helpful, I DID think that rendering the partial would cause a call to the controller. Is it impossible to have two (or more) tables on the same page that draw data from the same db table using different querys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly. Your problem is that you are expecting your two controller methods get called but it doesn't work that way.

When you visit a url, rails knows what controller and what controller action to call based on your routes.rb file configuration.

Since you are accessing the lastthree url (which I think should be named last_three if you are following conventions) your path might look like /lastthree. Based on the behavior you described I guess you have something like this in your routes.rb file

```
get '/lastthree', to: 'ownerships#lastthree'
get '/nextpick', to: 'ownerships#nextpick'
```

A request will always map to one controller action. The fact that you render your nextpick partial in the lastthree view doesn't mean that the nextpick method is being called at all. Controller methods are called based on the requested route not based on the rendering of the views.

To answer your question: yes, you can have both results. But for that you would need to either add a before_action or after_action callback in your controller to call the nextpick method or to call that method directly from your lastthree method. Also, you will need give the instance variables different names or else the method that gets called last will end up overriding the variable and you will end up in the same situation.

You might consider passing the variables as locals to your views in order to avoid your views depending on too many instance variables. As a good practice you should try only use one instance variable per view.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you!